# CustomHttpClient throwing timeout exception

Tags: android, io

I have this CustomHttpClient class, which I found in the net:

```
public class CustomHttpClient {


public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT=10000;
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

 private static HttpClient getHttpClient(){
     if(mHttpClient==null){
         mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
         HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
         HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
         ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
     }
     return mHttpClient;
 }

 public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {

     BufferedReader in = null;
     try{
         HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
         HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
         UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(formEntity);
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);//This is line 45, where the exception is thrown.
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
         String line = "";
         String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line + NL);
         }
         in.close();
         String result = sb.toString();
         return result;
     }finally{
         if (in!=null){
             try{
                 in.close();

             }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
         }
     }
}

public static HttpResponse ResponseExecuteHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {

     BufferedReader in = null;
     try{
         HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
         HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
         UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(formEntity);
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         return response;
     }finally{
         if (in!=null){
             try{
                 in.close();

             }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
         }
     }
}

 public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
         BufferedReader in = null;
     try{
         HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
         HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
         request.setURI(new URI(url));
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
         String line = "";
         String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line + NL);
             }
         in.close();
         String result = sb.toString();
         return result;
     } finally{
         if(in!=null){
             try{
             in.close();

         }catch (IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
}
}
```

I am using it this way:

```
(...)
entrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        user=login.getText().toString();
        String passtext=pass.getText().toString();
        parameters=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", user));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", passtext));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("movil", "si"));
        respuesta=null;
        try{
            Thread thread=new Thread(){
                public void run() {


            try {

                respuesta=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(urlogin, parameters);
                res=respuesta.toString();
(...)
```

I am aware that in 4.2.2 version of Android, every http call must be in another thread or it will rise an exception, but as you can see, the call is in another thread...but I am still getting a TimeoutException:

```
05-08 10:25:12.801: W/System.err(3191): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connection timed out
05-08 10:25:12.811: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
05-08 10:25:12.821: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-08 10:25:12.826: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-08 10:25:12.831: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-08 10:25:12.836: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-08 10:25:12.841: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-08 10:25:12.851: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-08 10:25:12.871: W/System.err(3191):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-08 10:25:12.886: W/System.err(3191):     at com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(CustomHttpClient.java:45)
05-08 10:25:12.891: W/System.err(3191):     at com.publidirecta.vinceriazafata.LoginActivity$3$1.run(LoginActivity.java:121)
```

The server is up, and the url is ok. I have tried surrounding the part of the code inside the CustomHttpClient class inside another thread, this way, but still doesn't works:

```
public static String executeHttpPost(final String url, final ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
     Thread thread=new Thread(){
         public void run(){
     BufferedReader in = null;

     try{

         HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
         HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
         UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(formEntity);
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
         String line = "";
         String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line + NL);
         }
         in.close();
         result = sb.toString();

     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
         if (in!=null){
             try{
                 in.close();

             }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();

             }
         }
     }
         }
     };
     thread.start();
     return result;
}
```

Any help with that exception? Thank you.

EDIT: Tried this las class with a phone with 2.3.4, and it works ok...

Tried with 2.3.6 version...and it does not work, neither...

Comment: Before I post a big answer, could I possibly check you've got `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, i have it in my Manifest. As you can see, that same code works perfectly in a 2.3.4 device.. And thanks to you!

Comment: What's your minimum API requirements? As this is a connection timeout, have you sat next to server-side with a wireshark to see if you're acking in the handshake? Also, have a go at a thirty second connection timeout, and indeed, it's generally bad practice to have the same time very different kinds of timeout.

Comment: Oh and this is definitely an http connection, no SSL?

Comment: I raise from 10 seconds to one minute, and still the same result(ConnectionTimeoutException). And my minimum requirements is API 8. And it is simply http, not secure connection by now (https).

Comment: And how soon does the exception get thrown into the timeout period?

Comment: It waits the whole minute...

Comment: Out of interest- what do you expect `respuesta` and `res` to be? They, of course, *won't* be what `sb.toString()` is in most cases. Did you want them to be?

Comment: Are both Strings. It's redundant, but I am trying everything due to desperation...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29587/discussion-between-tom-and-fustigador)